# C# LINQ sum array properties

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a class with an array of values, and a list of those classes.

And I want to return the sum (or any other operation) of all the items in the list, also as an array.

E.g. the sum of {1,2,3}, {10,20,30} & {100,200,300} would be {111,222,333}

So, the resulting array's 1st element will be the sum of all the 1st elements in the input arrays, the 2nd element will be the sum of all the 2nd elements in the input arrays, etc.

I can do it with:

```
    public class Item
    {
        internal int[] Values = new int[3];
    }

    public class Items : List<Item>
    {
        internal int[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                int[] retVal = new int[3];
                for (int x = 0; x < retVal.Length; x++)
                {
                    retVal[x] = this.Sum(i => i.Values[x]);
                }
                return retVal;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I feel that this should be achievable as a single line using LINQ. Is it?

Comment: `items.Select(item => item.Values.Sum()).ToArray()`

Comment: Surely the um of `{1,2,3}, {10,20,30} & {100,200,300}` would be `6, 60, 600` ?

Comment: Do you want to get an array with sum of every 1th, 3nd,.. n element of `Values` array? What happens, if the have a different length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using a single linq code line, using `Enumrable.Range`, `Max`, `Select` and `Sum`:

Notice I've also included a simple condition to save you from an `IndexOutOfRangeException` should one of the arrays is a different length than the others.

```
internal int[] ValuesLinq
{
    get
    {
        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, this.Max(i => i.Values.Length))
            .Select(ind => this.Sum(item => item.Values.Length > ind ? item.Values[ind] : 0))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>Rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/GJW11934)

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of doing the "Enumerable.Range(0, this.Max(i => i.Values.Length))" initial step (and bonus points for it working for any size arrays)

Comment: Actually, Dmitry's answer also works for multiple array sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to `Group` items withing the arrays by their indexes (so we sum all 1st arrays items, every 2nd items etc.):

```
int[] retVal = myList
  .SelectMany(item => item.Values
     .Select((value, index) => new {value, index}))
  .GroupBy(item => item.index, item => item.value)
  .Select(group => group.Sum())
  .ToArray();
```